# solving nonlinear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions, newtons-method

I have a homework question that I cannot answer. Here is the question prompt:

1. Deﬁne Eq. 8.3 and Eq. 8.4 in a function. This function should take a vector of joint angles ([image: \alpha] and [image: \beta]) as input and should return a column vector containing the two functions ([image: f_{1}] and [image: f_{2}]) evaluated at those angles. The function should contain the link lengths and values of [image: R{des}] and [image: H_{des} = 1.1] for calculation. Include your code in your solution.

Equations 8.3 and 8.4 are:

[image: formula] (8.3)

[image: formula] (8.4)

where

[image: d_{1} = d_{2} = 1.0]

[image: R{des} = 1]

[image: H_{des} = 1.1]

[image: \alpha = \left \langle 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right \rangle]

[image: \beta = \left \langle 0, \pi \right \rangle]

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function F = rob_arm (alphag, betag)
F = (1).*cos(alphag)+ (1).*(cos(alphag+betag))-(1) ;
  (1).*sin(alphag) + (1).*(sin(alphag+betag))-(1.1) ;
end
```

Because `alpha` and `beta` are matrices of different sizes, I used `meshgrid` to create `alphag` and `betag`, and used those matrices to calculate the values of `rob_arm`. After four hours of messing with this, I'm not even sure what the question is asking anymore, and the TA's are not currently answering emails. I wrote the following code, to try and force `rob_arm` into a single column:

```
alpha = 0:pi/100:(pi/2); %define angle alpha
beta = 0:pi/100:pi; %define angle beta

[alphag, betag] = meshgrid (alpha, beta); %mesh grid alpha and beta b/c different matrix dimensions
arm_pos = rob_arm (alphag, betag);

for ii = 1:1:101
    for k = 1:1:51
 col_vec (1,1:1:5151) = arm_pos(ii,k);
    end
end
```

Ignoring the query to create a column vector, the resulting output, `arm_pos` is good output. I can graph it and I get a very pretty picture of all the possible points that this robot arm can 'reach.'

But because I am dumb and have been trying this for many hours, it's not saving successive values of `rob_arm` into `col_vec`, it just replaces it each time and I end up with a 1x1 matrix. Ultimately, the goal will be to use the Newton-Raphson method to determine the zeroes of this function, but that's a long ways off. I am thinking if I can get all of the values calculated by `rob_arm` into a single column, then I can answer this question.

The next question is:

2. Create a separate function that accepts input of a single row vector containing the pair of angles [image: \alpha] and [image: \beta]. The output of the function should be the Jacobian (a 2 by 2 matrix). First, calculate the derivatives of Eqs. 8.3 – 8.4 by hand, then put them into your function. Include your function code in your solution

Which I will need to ask for clarification on, because I don't understand how a 1 x 51 matrix (`alpha`) and a 1 x 102 matrix (`beta`) could be accepted into a single row vector, that would then output a 2x2 matrix. I know what the Jacobian is, and it is the partial derivitives of my two functions, not a matrix of values.

If anyone wants to give me a hand, that would be super awesome.

Comment: Isn't this as simple to correct as returning the function value as a vector, `F = [ f1; f2 ]` with the corresponding expressions for `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: To ellaborate on LutzLs comment: try `function F = rob_arm (alphag, betag)
F = [(1).*cos(alphag)+ (1).*(cos(alphag+betag))-(1) ; ...
     (1).*sin(alphag) + (1).*(sin(alphag+betag))-(1.1)];
end`

Comment: Use a set of three dots "..." if continuing a statement between lines in MATLAB (in Octave it is not always necessary to have the dots...)

Answer (score 0):

You function definition is not right, you should use something like

```
function F = rob_arm (alphag, betag) 
 F = [(1).*cos(alphag)+ (1).*(cos(alphag+betag))-(1) ; ...   
      (1).*sin(alphag) + (1).*(sin(alphag+betag))-(1.1)]; 
end
```

Without the three dots " ... " MATLAB performs this calculation

```
 (1).*sin(alphag) + (1).*(sin(alphag+betag))-(1.1);
```

but does nothing with the result, and returns

```
  F = (1).*cos(alphag)+ (1).*(cos(alphag+betag))-(1) ;
```

which is not what you want, half the F values are missing.